# SharePoint Online - Delete folder from sharepoint using foldername

Tags: sharepoint

I've a requirement to delete folder (having pdf files) from SharePoint Online. I am using Microsoft Graph API.
Checking to see if I can use 'folder name' to find the folder in the SharePoint document library and delete the folder.

I have the complete SharePoint path (https://domainName.sharepoint.com/sites/POC/folderToBeDeleted). Can I use this path in Graph API to delete folderToBeDeleted including its content.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could delete the folder by name with this endpoint:

```
DELETE /drives/{drive-id}/root:/foldername
```

For nested folder:

```
DELETE /drives/{drive-id}/root:/folder1/.../folder2
```

And to retrieve the id of the document library:

```
GET /sites/{hostName}:/{optionalSubsiteUrl}:/drives
```

For example:

```
GET /sites/tenant.sharepoint.com:/sites/test:/drives
```

Comment: Michael, can you please provide the C# code for this using Microsoft Graph API. That would be really helpful.